# Error while creating a table from another one in Apache Spark

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, delta-lake

I'm creating the table the following way:

`spark.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table USING DELTA AS SELECT * FROM origin")`

But i get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Table implementation does not support writes: table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this `SparkException` error because this way to create a delta-lake table using a SQL request as input data is not implemented.

If you want to create a delta-lake table and insert data in the same time, you should use DataFrameWriter API, as explained in [databricks documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-batch.html#create-a-table):

```scala
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM origin")
  .write
  .format("delta")
  .save("/path/to/where/you/want/to/save/your/data")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was really confused by this other documentation (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-hiveformat.html) but your solution seems to work :)